# SCIPY library example align_vectors for least squares kabsch algorithm

Tags: python, api, scipy, least-squares

I am trying to run the align_vectors function within SciPy, however I am getting an error that the module has no attribute spatial.

Details on SciPy:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors.html?highlight=align#scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors

from command line:

```
/opt/local/bin/python3.5
import scipy as sc
sci.spatial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'spatial'
sci.version
<module 'scipy.version' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/version.py'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function fully,
scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors(A,B)